# angular ng-class statement with multiple conditions

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ng-class

I have to assign a class or an other to a field according two condition, one is about the position (it does not have to be the last one), the second is about a boolean parameter in my controller (my project is written using typescript and angular 1)

So i use: `ng-class="(ctrl.parameter || !$last) ? 'class1' : 'class2'"`
But it doesnt work.
Someone can help me

Thanks

Comment: ctrl or $ctrl? Any console errors?

Comment: it worked as it is written only changing '||' with '&&'
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the ternary conditions in ng-class.
it has to be like this

```
ng-class="{true: 'class1', false: 'class2'}[(ctrl.parameter || !$last)]"
```

Plunker
https://embed.plnkr.co/Pj5aEh4O0xNiNrVv2fBU/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary condition inside class itself.

```
class="{{(ctrl.parameter || !$last) ? 'class1' : 'class2'}}"
```